# Number of modes in cavity radiation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, waves, thermal-radiation

My question is that why do we consider **an octant of sphere** ( and calculate the volume of that shell to find the number of modes) but not another geometric object and its differential volume element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In $n$-space, the components $n_x$, $n_y$, and $n_z$ are the coordinate variables. Thus, they form a vector $\vec {N}$ which has magnitude given by

$$N^2 = n_x^2 + n_y^2 + n_z^2. $$

**Why a sphere?**

For analogy, consider a two dimensional $n$-space where $N^2 = n_x^2 + n_y^2$, where $N$ is the number of modes. Since this is the same for every combination of $n_x$, $n_y$; as a result, $N$ is constant. See the unit circle below: for each combination of $(n_x$, $n_y)$, a circle is the only geometry can keep $N$ (blue line) constant. A square, for example, would not work because $N$ would have to be longer to reach the corners than the sides.

[image]

The same is true for the sphere: in order to keep $N$ constant, you must have a sphere to accomodate all combinations of $n_x$, $n_y$, $n_z$.

**Why an octant?**

The number of modes $N$ is related to the volume by

$$ V = \frac{4}{3}\pi N^3. $$

Problem is, our components $n_x$, $n_y$, and $n_z$ can only take on positive values since they are also counting numbers. Only one octant of the sphere can meet this requirement to have all $n_x$, $n_y$, $n_z > 0$.

So you take an eighth of the total volume.

**Extra on spin**

If you are talking about counting electrons, EM modes (photons), etc. you also have to account for degeneracy when counting modes. For electrons, they are spin-1/2 particles, and thus for each possible mode in the cavity, that electron can either be spin-up or spin-down. So you would have to incorporate that as well.

Answer (score 0):

Each *linearally independent* mode counts as a unique micro state.

Notice $$\sin(kx) = -\sin(-kx)$$
so in this example $k$ and $-k$ are not unique modes. One is equal to the other with negative amplitude. So if we were to consider all the microstates in 1D, we'd just only consider the non-negative wavenumber $k$, and be sure each one state was unique.

In multiple dimensions, we choose each component of the wavevector to be non-negative, the same way. In three dimensions having all three components non-negative leave the octant allowed,  $\frac12 \cdot \frac12\cdot \frac12= \frac18$ of the total space.

The modes of a cavity will be something like $\sin \left( \frac{2\pi\mathbf{n}}{L}\cdot \mathbf{x}\right)$, where $\mathbf n$ is a vector of integers. So we consider the "octant" because only the non-negative values of $n_i$ count as unique states.